# Coldfusion Entity Association. What is the default setting for "lazy"

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Does anyone know what the default setting for lazy is with an entity association?  So if I have an association, is the association being lazy loaded or eager loaded when I don't specify?

for example

```
property name="Groups" fieldtype="many-to-many" cfc="ProfileGroup" type="array" singularname="Group" linktable="profile_group" fkcolumn="profileID" inversejoincolumn="groupID";
```

Will the Group entity be lazy or eager loaded, given I haven't specified which I want.

I just couldn't find this anywhere.. even the official CF documentation didn't say.

Thanks

Comment: Default fetch mode, according to JPA & Hibernate, `*-to-many => lazy`, and `*-to-one => eager`. It is distinct that `RHS many` should be lazily loaded, when `RHS one` should be eargly loaded. :)

Comment: Thanks Suninsky.. this is the clearest answer I have been able to find.. can you log this as answer and I'll flag.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes I've post it as answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default fetch mode is, according to **JPA & Hibernate**,

`*-to-many => lazy`

`*-to-one => eager`

It is distinct that **RHS many** should be *lazily* loaded, when **RHS one** should be *eagerly* loaded.

Answer (score 1):

> lazy: This is the **default** lazy loading that applies to collection
>   mapping, one-to-many and many-to-many relationship.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSE01EDE03-6E6B-4669-8C54-358460778450.html

Turn on `logSQL` and you can tell what's being lazy loaded (do not use cfdump/writedump)